# Next.js 13 App Router page transition now working

Tags: next.js13

I'm building a new website in Next.js 13 in TS and with the App folder, currently my `layout.tsx` looks like this:

```
export default function rootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return children
}
```

and the pages like this:

```
  return (
    <RootLayout
      title={seo.ES.title}
      description={seo.ES.description}
      url={seo.ES.home}
      alternateDefault={seo.ES.home}
      alternate={seo.EN.home}
    >
    ...
```

Is a dual language website, structure like this:

```
/
/page
/AnotherPage
/en
/en/morePages
```

Due to some hydration errors, I came out with a `RootLayout` Component that contains what usually you would put in the `layout.tsx`, it has the childer and the common components.

```
...
  <body>
    <Header language={textLang} />
    {children}
    <Footer language={textLang} />
    <CookieBanner />
  </body>
</html>
```

I was checking out some tutorials to implement page transitions effect (fade-in/out) but I couldn't make any of them work, any help to apply page transitions?